# Different value prefixes in JSON-LD context

Tags: namespaces, json-ld

So I have a predefined ontology and an existing JSON service (both times read as "can not change the existing content there") returning something like the following JSON:

```
{
  "propA": "someResource",
  "propB": "otherResource"
}
```

I'd like to transform that output to JSON-LD by adding (I can not change the existing attributes, but can add new ones) a context definition. In a first step I added a default context like this:

```
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "https://example.org/",

    "propA": { "@type": "@vocab" },
    "propB": { "@type": "@vocab" }
  },
  "@id": "https://example.org/blub",
```

This maps both resources to the namespace given by `@vocab` ([playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%22%2C%22propA%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40vocab%22%7D%2C%22propB%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40vocab%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fblub%22%2C%22propA%22%3A%22someResource%22%2C%22propB%22%3A%22otherResource%22%7D)).

```
<https://example.org/blub> <https://example.org/propA> <https://example.org/someResource> .
<https://example.org/blub> <https://example.org/propB> <https://example.org/otherResource> .
```

However, both referenced resources belong to two different namespaces. So what I need is some context, that maps to the following:

```
<https://example.org/blub> <https://example.org/propA> <https://foo.com/someResource> .
<https://example.org/blub> <https://example.org/propB> <https://bar.com/otherResource> .
```

Somewhere I found a [hack using `@base`](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%22%2C%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%22%2C%22propA%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%2C%22propB%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40vocab%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fblub%22%2C%22propA%22%3A%22someResource%22%2C%22propB%22%3A%22otherResource%22%7D), but this works only as a workaround, if you need one additional namespace not multiple ones.

**So how can I define separate namespace-prefixes for different properties, when I need more than two of those?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more fiddling around, I think JSON-LD 1.1 provides an answer: [scoped contexts](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#scoped-contexts).

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@version": 1.1,
    "@vocab": "https://example.org/",

    "propA": { "@type": "@id", "@context": { "@base": "https://foo.com/"} },
    "propB": { "@type": "@id", "@context": { "@base": "https://bar.com/"} }
  },
   "@id": "https://example.org/blub",

  "propA": "someResource",
  "propB": "otherResource"
}
```

There are two things to note:

- The addition of `"@version": 1.1` is crucial. This tells a compliant processor to use the JSON-LD 1.1 set of rules.
- We can then put each property in a separate context and change the `@base` here.

This will result in the following Turtle representation according to [this (dev) playground example](https://json-ld.org/playground-dev/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40version%22%3A1.1%2C%22%40vocab%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%22%2C%22propA%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%2F%22%7D%7D%2C%22propB%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2F%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fblub%22%2C%22propA%22%3A%22someResource%22%2C%22propB%22%3A%22otherResource%22%7D):

```
<https://example.org/blub> <https://example.org/propA> <https://foo.com/someResource> .
<https://example.org/blub> <https://example.org/propB> <https://bar.com/otherResource> .
```

---

*Sidenote*: We can even define an enumeration of possible value mappings in a similar way by setting `@type` to `@vocab` and defining the mapping the scoped context. Note, that this time we have to set `@vocab` in the scoped context instead of `@base`:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@version": 1.1,
    "@vocab": "https://example.org/",

    "propA": { 
      "@type": "@vocab", 
      "@context": { 
        "@vocab": "http://foo.com/", 

        "abc": "http://bar.com/abc", 
        "xyz": "http://baz.com/xyz"
      } 
    }
  },
   "@id": "https://example.org/blub"
}
```

Now depending on the value given to `propA` different namespaces are used ([play with it](https://json-ld.org/playground-dev/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40version%22%3A1.1%2C%22%40vocab%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2F%22%2C%22propA%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40vocab%22%2C%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%2F%22%2C%22abc%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com%2Fabc%22%2C%22xyz%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fbaz.com%2Fxyz%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fblub%22%2C%22propA%22%3A%22abc%22%7D)):

```
"abc" -> <https://example.org/blub> <https://example.org/propA> <http://bar.com/abc> .
"xyz" -> <https://example.org/blub> <https://example.org/propA> <http://baz.com/xyz> .
"mnl" -> <https://example.org/blub> <https://example.org/propA> <http://foo.com/mnl> .
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "dcat": "http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#",
    "org": "http://www.w3.org/ns/org#",
    "vcard": "http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#",
    "foaf": "https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema#",
    "dc": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/",
    "pod": "https://project-open-data.cio.gov/v1.1/schema#",
    "skos": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#",
  }
}
```

then you would use a CURIE format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURIE) to specify the `key:value` pair where the `key` is the `vocab` and the `value` is the `vocab term` used in the axiom/statement.

Comment: This would require me to change the values from `"someResource"` to `"skos:someResource"`, wouldn't it? As I mentioned I can not change the existing content, but just add some new properties.

Comment: ok, i should have read more closely. IMHO `@base` ain't gonna work - that's a shorthand for abbreviating your own namespace (as is often done in CSS where the root is default and references are relative). I don't see how to handle the narrow limits of your problem. Can you define a new `@graph` of your own design? We then might be able to link a term:value in your existing `@graph` to the new `@graph`

Comment: As shown in the playground link above `@base` can be abused for adding one more namespace. What I actually would expect, is an option to set `@base` on  a term level: `"propA": { "@base": "http://bar.com", "@type": "@id" }`. This should override the global `@base` for that term and allow expanding values using arbitrary prefixes.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion of `@graph`: From my (limited) understanding this would change the JSON structure, so I can not use it here. Other legacy systems depend on the current structure and values. My goal is to enable new ones using semantic techniques, without losing compatibility with those legacy systems.

Comment: wish i could help but can't think of a solution in the context of your limits. I can't see how you can get 2+ domains using `@base` but then again, i've never tried. bon chance.